# want to convert my date formate 21/10/60 to 21-10-1960

Tags: php, date

I want to change date format from "21/10/60" to 21-10-1960 in PHP

i am using this code:-

> $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', '21/10/60');
>
> echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

and I am getting output:-

> 2060-10-21

but I want in this:-

> 1960-10-21

How can i Do this.

Comment: i think you should use full year format. like what about date 21/10/13 , is it in 2013 or 1913 ?

Comment: how would you decide which century it should be??is that date should be of past?

Comment: it is date of birth field

so it should past

Comment: if i use 21/10/13 it sholud be 2013
but i use 21/10/15 it sholud be 1915 means we take 100 years between this

Comment: Why? Can no user of your website be born after the year 2000?

Comment: not right now 

in future it can be

because now minimum age is 16 years old

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned repeatedly in your comments, like this one: `minimum age is 16 years old`, it will always be 1900's. You simply need

```
list($d,$m,$y)=explode("/","21/10/60");
echo "$m-$d-19$y";    // m-d-Y
echo "19$y-$m-$d";    // Y-m-d
```

No date functions or complicated stuff is required. Its a simple mapping job. As long as your actual date is valid and conforms to the format you mentioned, this output will be valid as well.

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/214518)**